# How to open shared folder on local network Win10

Tags: windows-10

I have an address for the shared folder in network:

> \\SOMEUSER\folder

How can I open that folder?

Comment: The expected name is more like \\Computername\Sharedfoldername, what you simply put in explorer address bar. Not sure, if this is  the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes in a network are mostly grouped.
You can try:

`\\<groupOfNode>\<node>\[folder]`

If both of you use default group it can be like:

`\\workgroup\<node>\[folder]`

Answer (score 0):

Following latest update to win10 version 2004, I had a difficulty to re-connect to shared computers that use insecure guest logons.

Initial I tried to enable insecure guest logons through Administrative tools.

`Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Lanman workstation`

and set `Enable insecure guest logon` to `enable`

It appears this does not change the registry. You actually have to set this in the registry directly.

`regedit`

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters`

and set `AllowInsecureGuestAuth` to 1.

et voila I got my access to shared computer working again.